# Is it true that the orthogonal group $O(n)$ spans $M_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that the orthogonal group $O(n)$ spans $M_n(\mathbb{R})$? That is, can every $n$ by $n$ matrix with real coefficients be written as a linear combination of orthogonal matrices?

Comment: There is a difference between $SO(n)$ and $O(n)$, which do you mean?

Comment: Just a typo I meant the orthogonal group O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** : To prove it, it suffices to show that $O(n)$ spans the $E_{i,j}$ (matrices that are all $0$'s except in position $(i,j)$, where there's a $1$). 
For that, consider permutation matrices, and permutation matrices with a few $-$signs