# Center of $O(n)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $O(n)$ be the set of real $n$ by $n$ orthogonal matrices. Let $A$ be a real $n$ by $n$ matrix such that $AB=BA$. Prove:

(a) If $A$ is symmetric, then $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

(b) If $A$ is orthogonal, then $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

(c) If $A$ is invertible, then $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$

I figured out part (a): Pick $B\in O(n)$ so that $A=B^tAB=D$, where $D$ is diagonal. So $A$ is diagonal. Now Let $E\in O(n)$ be the elementary matrix that swaps two rows. Then $A=E^{-1}AE\implies$ each diagonal entry is the same, and since $det(A)=\pm 1$, $A=I$ or $A=-I$.

Does anyone have any suggestions for part (b) or (c)?

Comment: Are you allowed to use that orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable?

Comment: @probably_someone They aren't in general? If you take a rotation by 90 degrees in $\mathbb{R}^2$, that operator has no eigenvalues, so it can't be diagonalizable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot we weren't in an algebraically closed field.

Comment: In (a), it's not clear that $\mathrm{det}(A)=\pm 1.$ Thus, you can say $A=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R},$ but not that $\lambda=\pm1$.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're assuming $AB=BA$ for all $B\in O(n)$?

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. And yes, in all three cases, $AB=BA$. We're just changing the the type of matrix $A$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that your condition should be $AB=BA$ for **all** $B\in O(n)$.
This entails that $AB=BA$ for all $B$ in the $\Bbb R$-vector space generated by the elements of $O(n)$. I claim that is all of $M_n(\Bbb R)$.
Any matrix commuting with all other matrices is a scalar multiple of
the identity.

In the case $n=2$, the matrices
$$\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1},\quad \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1},\quad
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0},\quad \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$$
span $M_2(\Bbb R)$. One can do something similar for general $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering though, is there perhaps a way to see this that uses the fact that $A$ is orthogonal or $A$ is invertible? I assumed the question was trying to guide us by some kind of incremental argument, each time using a slightly "less nice" property than before, but maybe not. Either way, thanks again for your answer!

Comment: See this question about the vector space spanned by $O(n)$ : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301099/is-it-true-that-the-orthogonal-group-on-spans-m-n-mathbbr